# Mongoose population call (maybe?) hanging

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I'm following the [thinkster.io MEAN tutorial](https://thinkster.io/mean-stack-tutorial/) - everything works, but I tried to go off-piste a little, and I don't understand why my changes don't work. After my changes, GETting `/posts/<id>` simply never responds - node logs the request, but no response is sent.

#### Working code

```
router.param('post', function(req, res, next, id) {
  var query = Post.findById(id);

  query.exec(function (err, post){
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    if (!post) { return next(new Error('can\'t find post')); }
    req.post = post;
    return next();
  });
});

router.get('/posts/:post', function(req, res, next) {
  req.post.populate('comments', function(err, post) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }

    res.json(post);
  });
});
```

#### Broken code

All I've done is move the populate call up to the parameter handler (is that the correct term?) - to my mind, that should work - by the time the GET handler comes around, `req.post` should have it's comments populated, no?

```
router.param('post', function(req, res, next, id) {
  var query = Post.findById(id);

  query.exec(function (err, post){
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    if (!post) { return next(new Error('can\'t find post')); }

    post.populate('comments', function(err, spost) {
        if (err) { return next(err); }
        req.post = spost;
    });

    return next();
  });
});

router.get('/posts/:post', function(req, res) {
  res.json(req.post);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No because when you call return next(), the post.populate may not have finished yet.
On top of that you may be calling next two times (if populate failed with an error)

```
query.exec(function (err, post){
  if (err) { return next(err); }
  if (!post) { return next(new Error('can\'t find post')); }
  //return to ensure you can not call next two times
  return post.populate('comments', function(err, spost) {
      if (err) { return next(err); }
      req.post = spost;
      return next(); //then we are sure next is called only when post is attached to req
  });
});
```